# VK API Как из Standalone-приложения проверить валидность токена методом secure.checkToken?

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно для того что бы при каждом запуске приложения не запрашивалось VKSdk(scope) а только тогда, когда вытащенный из tokenFromSharedPreferences не проходил проверку валидности.

Пытаюсь методом https://vk.com/dev/secure.checkToken

Вместе с токеном передаю защищённый ключ приложения, формат запроса в итоге следующий:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/secure.checkToken?client_seсret=<MyClientSecret>&access_token=<MyToken>
```

На что получаю ответ:

> "error_code":5,"error_msg":"User authorization failed: server method is unavailable with user token.

Можно как-либо вообще вызвать метод сервера из приложения?

Answer (score 2):

Делать запросы к методам [`secure.*`](https://vk.com/dev/secure) можно только с помощью [специального токена](https://vk.com/dev/auth_server) (ключа доступа), который будет привязан не к аккаунту пользователя, а к приложению.

Получить его можно, сделав запрос к данному адресу:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=5.60&grant_type=client_credentials
```

`CLIENT_ID` и `CLIENT_SECRET` - ID и секретный ключ вашего приложения, которые можно узнать из его настроек. Полученный токен передавайте как обычно в параметре `access_token` при обращении к методам [`secure.*`](https://vk.com/dev/secure).

Обратите внимание на то, что обычный токен, как говорится в указанной вами ошибке, для работы с данными методами не подходит.

Comment: Так что получается, "специальный токен" и "user token" - это разные токены? И тогда даже если я получу специальный токен, его же только и смогу проверить методом secure.checkToken. Он (и только он) передаётся в методе secure.checkToken. Смысл тогда его проверки, нужно проверить пользовательский токен...

Comment: @Arvalon, верно. Еще существует третий вид токенов - ключи доступа сообществ.

Comment: @Arvalon, дело в том, что сервисный токен, в отличие от пользовательского, не имеет срока годности и он не может внезапно стать негодным, если только вы, владелец приложения, не измените его (или секретный ключ, если генерируете сервисные токены динамически). Поэтому сервисный токен нет смысла проверять. Смысл данного метода в том, чтобы проверить, что пользовательский токен принадлежит вашему приложению, а также узнать, валиден ли он. То есть данный метод принимает любые пользовательские токены, созданные через ваше приложение.

Comment: Опять запутался. Сервисный токен и специальный токен это одно и тоже? https://api.vk.com/method/secure.checkToken проверяет что? Сервисный или пользовательский токен? Если пользовательский - то всё опять по кругу с ошибки  "server method is unavailable with user token". Если же сервисный - то вопрос снимается, у меня standalone-приложение, авторизовываемое VK Android SDK, в них же вообще нет сервисного токена и он там не нужен.

Comment: @Arvalon, да, специальный токен и сервисный токен - одно и то же. Метод [`secure.checkToken`](https://vk.com/dev/secure.checkToken) проверяет пользовательские токены и токены сообществ, которые надо передавать в параметре `token`. А в параметре `access_token` передавайте ваш сервисный токен.

Comment: А, в метод secure.checkToken можно передать ДВА токена, и сервисный параметром access_token и пользовательский (сообщества) параметром token!? И если мне предпольжим нужна такая проверка мне отдельно необходимо получить СЕРВИСНЫЙ токен для моего приложения. И можно будет его зашить в приложение? Если в теории его замена не потребуется то можно будет так и оставить всё навсегда?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48385/discussion-between-arvalon-and-terron).

Answer (score 0):

```
VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
        if (newToken == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
```

Можно просто сделать проверку

```
VKSdk.wakeUpSession(this, new VKCallback<VKSdk.LoginState>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(VKSdk.LoginState res) {
            switch (res)
            {
                case LoggedIn:
                    startActivity();
                    break;
                case LoggedOut:
                    login();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {

        }
    });
```